# How do I create a new object from an instance of its base class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a base class, A, which has a method that returns an instance of itself:

```
class A
{
    protected DateTime P { get; private set; }

    protected A()
    {
        P = DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected A GetOneA()
    {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

I need to create instance of child class B based on A object.

```
class B : A
{
    private B(A a)
    {
        //help
    }

    public B GetOneB()
    {
        A a = A.GetOneA();
        return new B(a);
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you give a little more context of why you need to do this?  This seems like a bit of an odd patern.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.  First create a "copy" constructor and pass a class instance of A.  Inside this constructor you will need to copy all necessary attributes.

```
class A
{
  protected DateTime P { get; private set; }
  protected A(A copy){
      //copy all properties
      this.P = A.P;
  }
  protected A()
  {
    P = DateTime.Now;
  }

  protected A GetOneA()
  {
    return new A();
  }
```

}

Then just call the super classes copy constructor.

```
class B : A
{
  //help
  private B(A a) : base(a)
  {
  }

  public B GetOneB()
  {
    A a = A.GetOneA();
    return new B(a);
  }
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Further reading on copy constructors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116.aspx

Comment: "super"?  This is a C# question =D

Comment: shouldn't that be: `private B(A a): base(a)`?

Comment: fixed your syntax - you can't call the `base` constructor from code, only with constructor chaining.

Comment: @Feramef yeah, like that, but without the semicolon ;-)

Comment: yeah, copy pasted everything.

Answer (score 2):

You made the constructor for A protected. B already contains an A because it `is-an` A. When the constructor for B is called, it will implicitly call the default constructor for A. What your `GetOneB` method is doing is calling GetOneA, which allocates an `A`, followed by allocating a `B` that is copy-constructed with `A a` as the parameter.

There's an issue of separation of concerns. There's initialization and there's allocation. If a `B` is-an `A`, and `A`s can only be allocated a certain way, then `B` can not allocate only its `A` part a certain way and its `B` part another way. The whole `B` must be allocated in one manner, but the initialization of it can be done otherwise.

If `A` must be allocated in a manner different than the rest of `B`, then you must use containment and create a `has-a` relationship.

EDIT: We're talking C#, so most of that is irrelevant, because if you're working in C# you're probably not manually managing memory allocation. In any case, you don't need to call `GetOneA`, because `B` `is-an` `A` and `A`'s constructor is called when `B` is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not technically possile no. That is, if I understand your goal to be to set an instance of some class to have an independent "parent" instance. It's just quite logically wrong I suppose.

You'd do better explaning what you want to do. Perhaps you may just like to copy the properties of the object into your own; in that case it's quite straight foward ...